# Specify the datafile to create a table partition In a tablespace spanning multiple datafiles

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration, oracle12c

Say that I have two datafiles created on two separate drives (a SSD and a Nomal HDD). I can create a tablespace which will include both the datafiles. In a typical scenario oracle will handle where each schema object for the tablespace will go and manage the storage accordingly.

But i want to take advantage of the the two datafiles in different drives and use the datafile in the SSD for a table partition which contains data i use more frequently and use the datafile in the normal HDD to create the second partition of the same table which will hold data which are not frequently used.

Can this be achieved?

On a side note: Is there any other way to do this other than partitioning?

Comment: @JSapkota Thanks, I think this is the only possible way to do this. If you can post this as a reply I can mark this as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to specify datafiles for a partition of a table. Instead we can specify tablespace for a partition. So you can create two different tablespaces, one's datafiles resides in SSD and another's in normal HDD. And you can use these tablespaces as your IO requirements.

[Reference](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/partitioning-enhancements-11gr1)